# Laravel polymorphic relationship causes n+1 problem

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am using polymorphic relationship to create multiple types. I have a node and edge models that describe a network, and each node can be one of multiple types.

Node model has...

```
public function nodeable()
{
    return $this->morphTo();
}
```

And the Company model (one of the "types" of node) has...

```
public function node()
{
    return $this->morphOne(Node::class, 'nodeable');
}
```

When retrieving a list of Nodes with their associated "type" model, I call the following...

```
$nodes = Node::with('nodeable')->get();
return NodeResource::collection($nodes);
```

the node resource class NodeResource has...

```
return [
    'id' => $this->id,
    'entity_type' => $this->nodeable_type,
    'entity' => $this->when($this->nodeable, function () {
        if ($this->nodeable instanceof \App\Models\Property) {
            return new PropertyResource($this->whenLoaded('nodeable'));
        }
        if ($this->nodeable instanceof \App\Models\Individual) {
            return new IndividualResource($this->whenLoaded('nodeable'));
        }
        if ($this->nodeable instanceof \App\Models\Company) {
            return new CompanyResource($this->whenLoaded('nodeable'));
        }
        if ($this->nodeable instanceof \App\Models\Trust) {
            return new TrustResource($this->whenLoaded('nodeable'));
        }
    }),
];
```

This does seem to work, but when I look at the SQL run during this retrieval I find that I have a n+1 issue. The following query is run for every node...

```
select
  *
from
  `nodes`
where
  `nodes`.`nodeable_type` = 'App\Models\Property'
  and `nodes`.`nodeable_id` = 1
  and `nodes`.`nodeable_id` is not null
limit
  1
```

My issue is that I don't understand why I get n+1 seemingly pointless queries when I have with('nodeable') in the query?

After n+1 of the above have run, some more queries are run that make more sense to me....

```
select * from `individuals` where `individuals`.`id` in (1, 2, 3, 4)

select * from `trusts` where `trusts`.`id` in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)

select * from `companies` where `companies`.`id` in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)

select * from `properties` where `properties`.`id` in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)

select * from `nodes`
```

ADDITIONAL QUESTION: are the 5 queries above what an eager loaded polymorphic relationship looks like (if there were 4 nodeable types)? Normally, I would have expected a join, but my feeling is that this is how polymorphic eager loading would have to function

EDIT: If I do not use this resource the n+1 problem goes away. I do need to use this resource ultimately. In previous projects I have used the same mechanism and it has not resulted in n+1

EDIT2: Looking at the $nodes data before it is passed to the NodeResource, the nodeable data is present, meaning the with('nodeable') works.

EDIT3: I have tried simplifying the NodeResource to always return a PropertyResource (since all types are the same right now)...

```
'entity' => new PropertyResource($this->whenLoaded('nodeable')),
```

because it was suggested that the call to $this->nodeable in the NodeResource might be the issue. This did not resolve the n+1

EDIT4: I found the culprit. From within the nodeable resource classes I was calling 'node_id' => $this->node->id. I should have noticed that the erroneous n+1 queries were referring not to the nodeable models (i.e. the fetching of a nodeable) but the node model itself. My apologies to anyone involved with this ticket. But I learnt something of from the attempts to help so thanks.

Comment: Curious why you deleted [your old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75548266/laravel-polymorphic-query-leads-to-n1-problem), when you could have edited it, but oh well; moot point. I haven't used polymorphic relationships extensively, so I don't have an easy way to test/verify this, but to answer your "ADDITIONAL QUESTION", yes; that is what Eager Loading looks like in Laravel (polymorphic or otherwise). `->with()` doesn't use any kind of `JOIN` syntax 

Comment: @TimLewis I deleted because I thought it was confusing. Though the replacement was basically the same. I didn't know that deleted questions don't actually get deleted or I probably would  not have done it. Anyway, thanks for responding. EDIT: I was tempted to delete this comment too, but I thought better of it

Comment: @TimLewis regarding "->with() doesn't use any kind of JOIN syntax" is that only with polymorphic? I thought non-polymorphic eager loading would result in a join? That being a single query.

Comment: Yeah, no worries; it's better than not deleting the old question and posting it again;  people do that and get in a bit of hot water (as it's used to circumvent closed questions, etc.). Just a note for next time  And to my knowledge (again, limited with regards to polymorphic), using `->with()` for _any_ kind of relationship doesn't perform a `JOIN`; it collects the IDs needed to link to the other Model(s), and then performs a separate query. I believe there are 3rd party packages that change this, but I can't seem to find the one I'm thinking of 

Comment: Do you by chance have an auto loading of the Node when the nodeable is loaded ? the attribute `protected $with` in any of the nodeable classes

Comment: @N69S as my last edit mentions I was actually explicitly loading the node from within the nodeable resource class. Totally my fault. Thanks for responding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the culprit. From within the nodeable resource classes I was calling 'node_id' => $this->node->id. I should have noticed that the erroneous n+1 queries were referring not to the nodeable models (i.e. the fetching of a nodeable) but the node model itself. My apologies to anyone involved with this ticket. But I learnt something of from the attempts to help so thanks.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `$this->nodeable`, the resource will be retrieved if it is not loaded on the resource. So your `whenLoaded` call doesn't do that much since you currently try to retrieve it first and *then* you check if it has been loaded.

So you could improve your code to something like this:

```php
return [
    'id' => $this->id,
    'entity_type' => $this->nodeable_type,
    'entity' => $this->when($this->resource->relationLoaded('nodeable'), function () {
        if ($this->nodeable instanceof \App\Models\Property) {
            return new PropertyResource($this->nodeable);
        }
        if ($this->nodeable instanceof \App\Models\Individual) {
            return new IndividualResource($this->nodeable);
        }
        if ($this->nodeable instanceof \App\Models\Company) {
            return new CompanyResource($this->nodeable);
        }
        if ($this->nodeable instanceof \App\Models\Trust) {
            return new TrustResource($this->nodeable);
        }
    }),
];
```

If this doesn't fix your n+1 issue then something else is happening.

Comment: Thanks for responding. This change does not resolve the n+1 issue, though I also appreciate your comment regarding whenLoaded. I'm attempting to give myself the option of not returning the nodeable by not explicitly loading in when fetching nodes. Though I see that the test for instance type will probably mean they are already loaded. I'll have to think more.

Comment: just a hunch: maybe you are misreading the SQL queries that you are seeing as well because its odd that `App\Models\Property` is being retrieved for each and every node. If you happen to have 4 nodes, 1 of each type, then 4 queries will be executed because they come from 4 different tables

Comment: actually that was just an example the n+1 queries retrieved all types, but not the nodeable as I originally thought but the node actually. As I mention in edit4.